# How to set image as background using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to put an image as a background in a JavaFX scene, but my code isn't working.

Im trying to make a Battleship-game program in java eclipse but i'm stuck at a graphics problem.

public class WindowGUI extends Application{

```
Game game;
Image image;

public WindowGUI(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    new WindowGUI(game);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("Battleship");
    image = new Image ("C:\\Users\\amali\\git\\inf101.v19.sem2\\inf101.v19.sem2\\src\\window\\battleshipbackground.jpg");
    ImageView background = new ImageView(image);
    Button startButton = new Button("START");
    BorderPane newStack = new BorderPane();
    newStack.getChildren().add(startButton);
    newStack.getChildren().add(background);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(newStack, 1300, 860));
    stage.show();

    startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        //  START THE GAME
        }
    });


}
```

}

When I first tried to run it, it worked and a new window opened with a button in the center, but the bakcground was blank. When i try setting an image as background in the window, behing the 'start'-button, nothing happens..

Comment: Observe the [`Image.exception`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#exceptionProperty()) property to see if there are any errors trying to load the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do it is to use the `Background` class rather than trying to add an `ImageView` as a child of your `BorderPane`.

```
Image image = new Image("C:\\Users\\amali\\git\\inf101.v19.sem2\\inf101.v19.sem2\\src\\window\\battleshipbackground.jpg");

BackgroundSize size = new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, 
        BackgroundSize.AUTO, 
        false, 
        false, 
        true, 
        false);

Background background = new Background(new BackgroundImage(image,
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
        size));

newStack.setBackground(background);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [BackgroundImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) class.
or try this
[JavaFX How to set scene background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image)