# JavaFX 3D Background image

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to add a background image to my JavaFX 3D program, but it just translates the ImageView instead of setting it as the background. What am I missing?

I create the ImageView, and then add it to a separate Group object in the start method. The choiceLayout is another Group object.

```
Image image = new Image(Program.class.getResourceAsStream("picture.jpg"));
ImageView view = new ImageView(image);
view.setPreserveRatio(true);
view.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-image.getWidth() / 2, -image.getHeight() / 2, 800));
Group bg = new Group();
bg.getChildren().add(choiceLayout); 
bg.getChildren().add(view);

Scene choiceScene = new Scene(bg, 1024, 768, true);
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image

Comment: Unfortunately, I've seen that the method in that post only works with 2D applications.

Comment: What if you set the `fill` of the `Scene` to an `ImagePattern`?

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. For anyone coming to this question in the future, do sceneName.setFill(new ImagePattern(new Image("file")));

Comment: You can add that as an answer if you want.